# Impossible to compile using maven-compiler-plugin with Java higher than 1.8

Tags: java, maven, java-8, maven-plugin, maven-compiler-plugin

I have a NetBeans maven-based project that I want to switch from Java 1.8 to 12 but I can't compile it.

After many attempts, I have decided to start from the beginning, and create a very simple project to understand how to do this change.

Well, I have tried and I can't compile the simple project either.

Could someone explain what I am doing wrong?

**Preamble**

NetBeans: 10.0

JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12 (I have tried also 9, 10, 11)

Maven:
[image: Console output of Maven]

**Project creation**

1. Create Project with a Window (first TopComponent)

[image: Netbeans display window]

2. I changed the JDK version from 11 (default in NetBeans 10.0) to 12

[image: Project properties in NetBeans]

3. This is the autogenerated POM with and the javax.annotation-api Dependency

   ```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
       <groupId>it.prj</groupId>
       <artifactId>Project-parent</artifactId>
       <version>2.9</version>
   </parent>
   <artifactId>Project-source</artifactId>
   <packaging>nbm</packaging>
   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
               <artifactId>nbm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <extensions>true</extensions>
               <configuration>
                   <useOSGiDependencies>true</useOSGiDependencies>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>
                   <useDefaultManifestFile>true</useDefaultManifestFile>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
           <artifactId>org-netbeans-api-annotations-common</artifactId>
           <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
           <artifactId>org-openide-windows</artifactId>
           <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
           <artifactId>org-openide-util</artifactId>
           <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
           <artifactId>org-openide-util-ui</artifactId>
           <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
           <artifactId>org-openide-util-lookup</artifactId>
           <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
           <artifactId>org-openide-awt</artifactId>
           <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
           <artifactId>org-netbeans-modules-settings</artifactId>
           <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
           <version>1.3.2</version>
           <type>jar</type>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <properties>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   </properties>
   ```
4. Then I start the Clean & Build > **SUCCESS**
5. I changed the Java version from 1.7 to 12

[image: Changing java version in properties]

This add the related Plugin to the POM

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>12</source>
                <target>12</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

6. Update the version field, so it becomes:

   ```
      <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.8.0</version>
           <configuration>
               <source>12</source>
               <target>12</target>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
   ```
7. Then I restart the Clean & Build > **FAILED**

   ```
   cd D:\Project\Project-source; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-12" "M2_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\apache-maven-3.6.0" cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Program Files\\apache-maven-3.6.0\\bin\\mvn.cmd\" -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\Netbeans 10.0\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 clean install\""
   ```

   Building Project-source 2.9

   --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ Project-source ---

Deleting D:\Project\Project-source\target

```
--- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ Project-source ---

Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
Copying 1 resource

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ Project-source ---
Changes detected - recompiling the module!
Compiling 1 source file to D:\Project\Project-source\target\classes

--- nbm-maven-plugin:4.1:manifest (default-manifest) @ Project-source ---
NBM Plugin generates manifest
Adding OSGi bundle dependency - javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:nbm-maven-plugin:4.1:manifest (default-manifest) on project Project-source: 
Execution default-manifest of goal org.codehaus.mojo:nbm-maven-plugin:4.1:manifest failed.: IllegalArgumentException
```

**EDIT**

8. i have tried to remove **nbm-maven-plugin** as suggested but this change the structure of Project and i don't know how to reinclude this module

[image]

Comment: `nbm-maven-plugin` fails, not the compilation. Temporarily remove `nbm-maven-plugin` from your build and see if it works.

Answer (score 4):

Please use the 4.2 version like this:

```
<groupId>org.apache.netbeans.utilities</groupId>
<artifactId>nbm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>4.2</version>
```

replacing any references to:

```
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
 <artifactId>nbm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

jar file generated by jdk>8 cannot be parsed by older version of the plugin.

Comment: works up to version 4.5, from 4.6 to 4.8 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF error occurs, BUT POINTING THE RIGHT PATH OF MANIFEST.MF

Answer (score 2):

In your example `nbm-maven-plugin` fails but the compilation process is fine.

Temporarily remove `nbm-maven-plugin` from your build and see if Maven can build without it. Perhaps you can skip this plugin altogether as it seems specific only to NetBeans IDE.

Comment: Yes, removing the plugin the build works; the new problem is that the row "<packaging>nbm</packaging>" is not recognized anymore and removing it, project will not work

Comment: `nbm-maven-plugin` seems to be no longer maintained according to [Github](https://github.com/mojohaus/nbm-maven-plugin/tree/master/nbm-maven-plugin), it might not work with recent Java versions unless someone is maintaining it.